# Which integration should I use to boost the (rf signal out pin) of the MVE1600 voltage controlled oscillator?

Tags: vco

[image]

[image]

With which IC can I boost the signal on the rf out pin of the MVE1600 voltage controlled oscillator? I lowered the function generator to 500 micro amps by connecting 10k resistor.So it is equal to MVE1600 rf out pin.And simulated to increase it with 74HC04D but I got an error. It has only 3.75 volt 500 mikroamper rf out pin. It is problem.

Which integration should I use to boost the (rf signal out pin) of the MVE1600 voltage controlled oscillator?

The model of the voltage controlled oscillator is in the picture

Comment: Your circuit is going to burn rapidly; you need base resistors.

Comment: Okay I added resistors but no different . I can not see any signal in oscilloscope. I want to increase amperage MVE 1600 VCO rf out pin and see signal 12 volt

Comment: Your transistor circuit (with added base resistors) only works when the input signal goes below about 0.5 volts or above 11.5 volts approximately. At all points between, both transistors are activated and so the DC output will be about 3 volt to maybe 9 volts and, unless you have some form of current limit protection both transistors will likely still fry.

Comment: If both transistors are activated, my signal may be disappearing for this reason. What should I do to protect current?

Comment: But mve1600 has only 3.75 volt 500 mikroamperage. It can be burn transistors ?

Comment: If both transistors are on you'll potentially have hundreds of mA flowing from the 12 volt rail to ground.

Comment: But it doesn't work again. How can I increase the low rf voltage output of the mve1600 voltage controlled oscillator by 500 microamps?

Comment: Sorry, you are going to have to post the schematic that doesn't work.